# getElementsByName fails but getElementById works Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Using either `document.getElementsByName('spanName')` or `jQuery('[name="spanName"]')` fails (returning []) when
called from within a Chrome extension (or console). However, `document.getElementById('spanId')` works, as does a CCS selector on a class name.

The span is already part of the DOM, prior to any intervention by the extension. However, the name attribute was added by the extension, the style attribute was modified, and a class name was added:

**Original:**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <span style="background-color:Yellow">Some highlighted text</span>
</div>
```

**Updated:**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <span id"spanId" name="spanName" class="highlighted" style="">Some highlighted text</span>
</div>
```

In addition, at one point the entire `parentDiv`'s innerHTML is replaced and the spans are transferred

```
let spanNodeList = ...
let newInnerHTML = ...
let patterns = ...

for (let i = 0; i < spanNodeList.length; i++) {
    newInnerHTML.replace(patterns[i], spanNodeList[i].outerHTML)
}

document.getElementById('parentDiv').innerHTML = newInnerHTML
```

I am performing this transfer *before* adding the name attribute. Could this innerHTML replacement be the source of my woes?

**By the Way...**

I'm updating the spans with:

```
let spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span')
spans[Symbol.Iterator] = [][Symbol.Iterator]

for (let span of spans) {
   if (!/yellow/i.test(span.style.CSSText) continue;
   span.style.CSSText = ''
   span.id = <uniqueSpanId>
   span.name = 'spanName'
   span.className = "highlighted'
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"

Comment: try adding a class to them instead ... name isn't generally used other than form elements. Might not be part of method

Comment: if you are trying getElementsByName **before adding the name attribute** I think the problem is abundantly obvious

Comment: You might consider posting a minimal example that demonstrates the issue, perhaps replicating the DOM modifications using buttons or similar. Why are you "transferring" nodes using outerHTML? Why not just assign the nodes to their new parent using *insertBefore* or similar?

Comment: you missed `=` after `span id`

Comment: have you tried invoking getElementsByName again after you've replaced the parent div's innerHTML?

Answer (score 1):

Per the spec, `document.getElementsByName()` returns an array of elements. You will either have to loop through the result or do `document.getElementsByName('spanName')[0]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Comment: Updated to clarify. I I'm getting `[]` returned.

Comment: I see. Perhaps Chrome extensions do not have that method? I suppose there are no JS errors? You can open another Chrome developer tools to inspect your extension as you would a website.

Answer (score 0):

My testing agrees that:

document.getElementsByName(name) does not work from chrome extensions,

but

document.getElementById(id) works, and
document.getElementsByTagName(name) works too.

If you really need to use getElementsByName, a possible solution may be to inject a script into the page, like this:

```
function getEls() {
    // This should work when it runs in the original page
    let results = document.getElementsByName('spanname');

    // but we have to shuttle the results back to the content script
    document.body.setAttribute('data-myresults', my_encode(results));
}

// Runs "func" in the page we are attached to
function injectScript(func) {
    const codeString = '(' + func + ')();';
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = codeString;
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}

injectScript(getEls);

// then, after it has had enough time to asynchronously do the job...
let results = my_decode(document.body.getAttribute('data-myresults'));
```

(Also, you will have to write my_encode to convert your data to a string, and my_decode to do the opposite.)